# Find index of a value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Can linq somehow be used to find the index of a value in an array?

For instance, this loop locates the key index within an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    if (words[i].IsKey)
    {
        keyIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
int keyIndex = Array.FindIndex(words, w => w.IsKey);
```

That actually gets you the integer index and not the object, regardless of what custom class you have created

Answer (score 72):

For arrays you can use:
[`Array.FindIndex<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx):

```
int keyIndex = Array.FindIndex(words, w => w.IsKey);
```

---

For lists you can use [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx):

```
int keyIndex = words.FindIndex(w => w.IsKey);
```

---

You can also write a generic extension method that works for any [`Enumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
///<summary>Finds the index of the first item matching an expression in an enumerable.</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search.</param>
///<param name="predicate">The expression to test the items against.</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if no items match.</returns>
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

    int retVal = 0;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (predicate(item)) return retVal;
        retVal++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

And you can use LINQ as well:

```
int keyIndex = words
    .Select((v, i) => new {Word = v, Index = i})
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Word.IsKey)?.Index ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
int keyIndex = words.TakeWhile(w => !w.IsKey).Count();
```

Comment: +1 but, what if item doesn't exist? we will get 0, but the index is -1

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan If the item doesn't exist, this yields words.Length

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan You wrote "we will get 0" ... that was wrong. You wrote "but the index is -1" ... that also is wrong. -1 is a common indicator of failure, but it's not the only possible one. Any value not within 0..words.Length-1 will do.

Comment: @JimBalter, I mean if item does not exist expression will return 0, what is wrong in it? I agree that -1 is common indicator, but agree that it is obvious that 99% cases -1 is expected value when item does not exist. at least 0 is wrong when item does not exist

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find the word you can use

```
var word = words.Where(item => item.IsKey).First();
```

This gives you the first item for which IsKey is true (if there might be non you might want to use `.FirstOrDefault()`

To get both the item and the index you can use

```
KeyValuePair<WordType, int> word = words.Select((item, index) => new KeyValuePair<WordType, int>(item, index)).Where(item => item.Key.IsKey).First();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
var key = words.Where(x => x.IsKey == true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just posted my implementation of IndexWhere() extension method (with unit tests):

http://snipplr.com/view/53625/linq-index-of-item--indexwhere/

Example usage:

```
int index = myList.IndexWhere(item => item.Something == someOtherThing);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me more, from [msdn microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d02c96a-b3db-4e67-9b54-c08dbb5cc988/row-number-in-linq-query?forum=csharpgeneral):

```
var result =  query.AsEnumerable().Select((x, index) =>
              new { index,x.Id,x.FirstName});
```

`query` is your `toList()` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = -1;
index = words.Any (word => { index++; return word.IsKey; }) ? index : -1;
```