# Getting the index of a particular item in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to retrieve the index of an array but I know only a part of the actual value in the array.

For example, I am storing an author name in the array dynamically say "author = 'xyz'". 
Now I want to find the index of the array item containing it, since I don't know the value part.

How to do this?

Comment: are you using `Array` or `string []`?

Comment: its a string[] and i want to find something Array.Indexof(arrFilter, "author") here author is not the complete value rather a part of the complete value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find index of a value in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764970/find-index-of-a-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=VS.100).aspx)

```
 var index = Array.FindIndex(myArray, row => row.Author == "xyz");
```

Edit: I see you have an array of string, you can use any code to match, here an example with a simple contains:

```
 var index = Array.FindIndex(myArray, row => row.Contains("Author='xyz'"));
```

Maybe you need to match using a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)?

Comment: One could also make this [an array extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148881/1275774 "see my answer on this question") for easier use and IntelliSense.

Answer (score 16):

try `Array.FindIndex(myArray, x => x.Contains("author"));`

Answer (score 15):

```
     int i=  Array.IndexOf(temp1,  temp1.Where(x=>x.Contains("abc")).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 10):

The previous answers will only work if you know the exact value you are searching for - the question states that only a partial value is known.

```
Array.FindIndex(authors, author => author.Contains("xyz"));
```

This will return the index of the first item containing "xyz".

Answer (score 7):

## FindIndex Extension

```
static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static int FindIndex<T>(this T[] array, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        return Array.FindIndex(array, match);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
int[] array = { 9,8,7,6,5 };

var index = array.FindIndex(i => i == 7);

Console.WriteLine(index); // Prints "2"
```

[Here's a fiddle with it.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LMJH6)

---

### Bonus: IndexOf Extension

I wrote this first not reading the question properly...

```
static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOf<T>(this T[] array, T value)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(array, value);
    }   
}
```

Usage

```
int[] array = { 9,8,7,6,5 };

var index = array.IndexOf(7);

Console.WriteLine(index); // Prints "2"
```

[Here's a fiddle with it.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D0MEO6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.IndexOf()` method.

```
var index = Array.IndexOf(myArray,valueToFind);
```