# How to find the position(not Id) of an Item in a sorted Linq list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of an Item which is

```
public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
     }
public DbSet<Item> ItemSet { get; set; }
```

Now in my controller I get the list of ItemSet as a paged

```
var mainItem = db.ItemSet.Find(id);
if(mainItem != null)
{
var ItemsList = db.Itemset.OrderBy(By Some Order).ThenBy(Another order).ToList();
var pg = page ?? 1; // need page number equal to page number of Item.
var list = ItemsList.ToPagedList(pg, 10);
}
```

In this example I need to know the position of the `mainItem` in `ItemsList` to get to the appropriate page number for the item in the List. How do I get the `PageNumber` or `no of Items before mainItem` or the `position of mainItem` using Linq?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get index of an object in a Generic list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419278/get-index-of-an-object-in-a-generic-list)

Comment: It seems as if you actually want the page-index not the item-index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes Tim thats right. But I have searched documentation for MVC PagedList and it dosen't provide a method. So I am doing it this way.

Comment: @FloodGravemind: i'm not that familiar with a `PagedList` or L2E but you can get the page-number from the index of an item and the page-size easily.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the index of the item

```
int index = ItemList.FindIndex(item => item.Id== mainItem.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List<T>.FindIndex Method (Predicate<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int position = ItemList.FindIndex(r => r.Id == mainItem.Id);
```