# Does Array provide a way to search for index of an element with arbitrary logic

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any lambda-based approach which will allow one to find the index of (the first) occurrence of an element in an array based on custom logic?

I know I can find the *element* itself using `Array.First` but can I find the index of that element without manually iterating the array?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the index of the specific element by its value?

Comment: You mean based on a property value? There is `Array.IndexOf` for the object itself.

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` ?

Comment: `Array` and `List` both have convenience methods for this; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1290603/4137916) for a more general question on doing this for any `IEnumerable` (all those answers are easily extended to predicates rather than specific values, where desired).

Comment: If you call Array.IndexOf(), the iteration happens through the array. But if I understand the question correctly, you want the index of the first item you were looking for. But you don't want to iterate through the whole array or part of the array. Unfortunately, this is impossible if the element is not at the beginning or end of the array. This is due to the mechanism of how arrays are built.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the index of a particular item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388600/getting-the-index-of-a-particular-item-in-array)

Comment: I just edited the question as I realised IndexOf is not quite adequate.

Comment: the accepted answer in the second duplicate should still satisfy your criteria. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.IndexOf()`. Example:

```
var array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var index = Array.IndexOf(array, "two");
// index = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) that *"Searches for the specified object and **returns the index of its first occurrence** in a one-dimensional array or in a range of elements in the array."* :

```
var foo = new int [] { 10, 42, 42, 51, 42, 100 };

Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(foo, 42)); // output is 1
```

Although this will iterate under the hood, you don't have to *manually [iterate] the array*

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var s = new string[] {"foo", "bar"};
var index = Array.FindIndex(s, s1 => s1 == "foo"); // returns 0
```

NOTE: it will return `-1` if the element was not found

Comment: I was sure something existed but forgot to check static members. Why I wonder is it only available that way?

Answer (score 0):

There's the Array.IndexOf method.

The following code:

```
    String[] strings = { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
                 "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "in", "the",
                 "barn" };
    Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(strings, "dog"));
```

Will output 8.

MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof