# Why I'm always getting IndexValue -1 of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin, mvvm

I'm always getting indexValue -1 of `ProductType[]` Array, when I select array of product value.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

ViewModel:

```
public ProductType[] ProductTypesSel { get; set; }
private int _ProductTypeIndex = -1;

public int ProductTypeIndex
{
    get { return _ProductTypeIndex; }
    set
    {
        _ProductTypeIndex = value;

        if (value >= 0)
        {
            Item.ProductType = ProductTypesSel[value].Code;
        }
        
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProductTypeDisp));
        Console.WriteLine(ProductTypeDisp);
    }
}
public string ProductTypeDisp => Config != null && ProductTypeIndex >= 0 && ProductTypeIndex < ProductTypesSel.Length ? ProductTypesSel[ProductTypeIndex].Name : null;
```

Codebehind:

```
int indexValue = Array.IndexOf(_Model.ProductTypesSel, productValue);
_Model.ProductTypeIndex = indexValue;
```

Comment: What's the type of the `productValue`?

Comment: `string` type @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: The `productValue` should be the same type as the `ProductTypesSel`. Such as the `productValue` is `string`, the `ProductTypesSel` should be the `string[]`.

Comment: I'm using like this, `string productValue = _Model.ProductTypesSel[i].Name; ` @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: i'm getting name of product, but i need to get index value of name @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please make sure the property `Name` in the ProductType is public, such as:

```
public class ProductType
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can try to use the Array.FindIndex:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(_Model.ProductTypesSel, t => t.Name ==productValue);
// or use the code below
int i=  Array.IndexOf(_Model.ProductTypesSel,  _Model.ProductTypesSel.Where(x=>x.Name==productValue).FirstOrDefault());
```

For more information, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388600/getting-the-index-of-a-particular-item-in-array).

Comment: Now i'm getting correct index value, Thank you so much @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Answer (score 3):

because you are searching by value `value3`, not by `Value3`. your array has `Value3`. and arrays don't find by case insensitive.

for case insensitive search you can use this

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "Value0", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5" };
int index = Array.FindIndex(arr, t => t.IndexOf("value3", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on t.IndexOf  `ProductType does not contain a definition for 'IndexOf' and the best extension method overload` @vivek

Comment: I'm doing like this , `int indexValue = Array.FindIndex(_Model.ProductTypesSel, t => t.IndexOf(productValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);` @viveknuna

Comment: Because `ProuctTypesSel` is type of `ProuctType[]` not the `string[]`. @Raj

Comment: @Raj I will leave that you to fix by yourself. Because the root cause and fix has been addressed. You just need to tweak