# VB.NET Find a string in an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am new to VB.net, usually a Python or Matlab programmer.I have begun programming in VB.Net. I am battling to reference an index of a string in an array without looping through a for loop

How can I find an entry in an array in one line? My thinking is this..

```
Dim indx As Integer
Dim MyArray() As String   

indx = MyArray.find("ThisEntry")
```

or the index of

```
indx = MyArray.indexof("ThisEntry")
```

So far all I have found is function describing a method directly after you declare the variable? Am I missing something? or does the logic not make sense?

Comment: There is always going to be a loop somewhere, its just a matter of whether you call it or offload the capability to another function or method.

Comment: What do you mean by "So far all I have found is function describing a method directly after you declare the variable" sorry but I can't parse that statement, could you clarify it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764970/linq-used-to-find-index-of-value

Comment: @YaugenVlasau: That's C#, not VB .NET

Answer (score 15):

Do it this way, after you have some content on your array, that now is empty:

```
Dim result As String = Array.Find(MyArray, Function(s) s = "ThisEntry")
```

To get the index:

```
Dim index As Integer = Array.FindIndex(MyArray, Function(s) s = "ThisEntry")
```

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Maybe Extension methods are not really suitable for a beginner...

Comment: Yeah I prefer a thousand times C# style but....

Comment: +1 for [Array.FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.findindex.aspx).

Comment: Where is the +1? @Neolisk :P :P

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: Sorry, got distracted by something else. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

IndexOf works, you're just not using it correctly.

```
Dim arr As String() = {"aa", "bb", "cc"}

index = Array.IndexOf(arr, "bb")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim MyArray() As String = {"a", "ThisEntry", "b"}
Dim indx As Integer = MyArray.ToList().IndexOf("ThisEntry")
```

Comment: .ToList() creates a copy of the array which is a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim numbers As String() = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}

    Console.WriteLine(numbers.ToList().FindIndex(Function(x) x = "bbb"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you passing "what" variable to findbbb function?