# VB.net Search for String in Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

trying to figure out how I can search for a string in my arrays. As of now, I only figured out how to search through integers. My array is like this:

```
Dim IDno() As String = {264, 951, 357}
Dim author() As String = {"Peter", "Nathan", "Sandy"}
```

So as of now, if someone types in the number 951, my listbox will display:

ID#: 951

Name: Nathan

I want to know how I can allow users to search for names instead and it will display the ID# and the Name.

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713474/vb-net-find-a-string-in-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET Find a string in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713474/vb-net-find-a-string-in-an-array)

Comment: @AndrewMorton You mean, a duplicate of a duplicate?!

Comment: @David Yes, this seems to be more of a match to the one I referred to (and muffi spotted in the first place) than the root one. Of course, the reader can follow back to the root one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Array.FindIndex` - Only if all values/IDs are going to be unique.

Something along the lines of this should do the trick for you.

```
Dim ind As Integer = Array.FindIndex(IDno, "yourID")
Dim name As String = author(ind)
```

I've not got VS to hand to test this but off the top of my head, that should work. Although, as I said, it's only going to work if all the ID numbers are unique. (And obviously replace `"yourID"` with the ID you're using).