# Get matching index for a number in array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I'm new to programming and I've got confused on how to display the index number of a value in an array. I want to be able to type a random number and if the number I have entered is in the array, then it should tell me what the position (index) of the number is within the array.

For example if I enter the number 6, and 6 is in my array and it's index is 4, then the output should be "That number exists, it is positioned at 4 in the array". I've tried to do this but my code is the reverse of this, for example if I type in 6, then it looks for index 6 and outputs the number corresponding to index 6.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace searcharray
{ 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;

        Random r = new Random();



        int[] a;

        a = new int[n + 1]; 

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            a[i] = r.Next(1, 100); 


        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(" a [" + i + "] = " + a[i]);



      Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if (a.Contains(b))

        {

            Console.WriteLine("That number exists and the position of the number is: " + a[b]);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number doesn't exist in the array");
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
}
```

Comment: [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) will give you the index or -1 if not found.  Also arrays are zero based so `a[0]` is going to be 0 (the default value) since it's never set to another value.  If you want to display a 1 based index, just add 1 to the result for the display, but stick with 0 based otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the index of a particular item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388600/getting-the-index-of-a-particular-item-in-array)

Comment: See also [Find index of a value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764970/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.IndexOf`(gives you the index of given value in Array) instead of `a[b]` like this:

```
if (a.Contains(b))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That number exists and the position of the number is: " + Array.IndexOf(a, b));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number doesn't exist in the array");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Array.IndexOf() like below:

```
Console.WriteLine("That number exists and the position of the number is: " + Array.IndexOf(a, b));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array.IndexOf returns -1 if the item dont exists in the array

```cs
var itemIndex = Array.IndexOf(a, b);
if (itemIndex != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That number exists and the position of the number is: " + itemIndex);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number doesn't exist in the array");
}
```